# jQuery animate div when filled

Tags: jquery

Here is a very simple example of what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/MxKLU/

Click on the links `space-one` and `space-two` and the contents within the div `space` will change. This will cause a jaring seen by the red background, when the contents gets larger and smaller than its predecessor. I am looking for a way to animate the height of the div `space` so that this jaring does not occur. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it like this

```
$("#space").css("height",$(".selected").height());

$('#space-one-appear').click(function(){
    $('#space-one').attr('class','selected');
    $('#space-two').attr('class','unselected');
    $("#space").animate({height:$(".selected").height()}, 500);
});

$('#space-two-appear').click(function(){
    $('#space-two').attr('class','selected');
    $('#space-one').attr('class','unselected');
    $("#space").animate({height:$(".selected").height()}, 500);
});
```

jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/MxKLU/5/

Answer (score 3):

Hope it helps you.

```
$('a[id^="space"]').click(function(){
      $('div#space div').hide();
      $('#space, #'+$(this).text()).slideDown();
 });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MxKLU/2/

Answer (score 3):

My proposition:
http://jsfiddle.net/dxvEr/3/

it does not need to change height to 0 in the middle of the process.

I've added another div. Outer div has overflow:hidden and static height so it wouln't react to change in its content, but we check inner div height and use animation to set outer div to the same height.